# Creating Virtual Field in QGIS Python Console

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-python-console, virtual-field

Is there any example about how to create a virtual field and subsequently change the attribute of a non-virtual field without wiping out the virtual field? Both are required to be done in the Python Console.

Comment: Good question as I use Virtual Fields quite a lot. I also noticed the _Field Calculator_ in QGIS Modeler doesn't have an option to insert virtual fields so it would be interesting to see how to achieve this via the console.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you have a variable `layer` that is a reference to a vector layer you need

- to specify the field definition
- add the new field with an expression

  ```py
   field = QgsField('twoTimesA', QVariant.LongLong)
   layer.addExpressionField(' 2 * "A" ', field)
  ```

You can now modify an attribute and when you query the layer next time the virtual field will be updated.