# Add Temp Attribute to Readonly WFS map

Tags: qgis, python, wfs, fields-attributes

I have been working on a QGIS plugin. I have run into some problems and to solve it, one of the solutions would be to add a column to the WFS layer. However most of the times, I have not the permission to edit the WFS layer. I was wondering whether it would be possible to create a kind of temp attribute to each feature. It does not have to be persistent, so I only needed at runtime. Would something like this be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want a virtual field.

[image]

Comment: Is there API functionality exposed that can add a virtual field?

Comment: That I do not know.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I need. Yes it is possible to do it from Python. See this post: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144241/how-to-create-a-virtual-field-in-qgis-by-python-console