# Creating Virtual Field from QGIS Python Console

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-python-console, virtual-field

I would like to create a new virtual field with a specific expression (like 2*"ID") on an existing layer. Is it possible to do so from the Python console?

I've tried using `addExpressionField` followed by `updatefields` as suggested in a similar question ([Creating Virtual Field in QGIS Python Console](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144241/how-to-create-a-virtual-field-in-qgis-by-python-console)) but when I manually check my layer fields from QGIS, nothing changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to get the [`addExpressionField()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a041b1d9f334eb3c31c893f5d130f7f0d) method from the `QgsVectorLayer` class with this:

```py
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsField
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

layer = iface.activeLayer()

layer.startEditing()
field = QgsField('twoTimesID', QVariant.String)
layer.addExpressionField(' 2 * "id" ', field)
layer.commitChanges()
```

---

**References:**

- [QGIS GitHub | test_qgsfeatureiterator.py](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/tests/src/python/test_qgsfeatureiterator.py)
- [Hot Examples | Python QgsVectorLayer.addExpressionField Examples](https://python.hotexamples.com/examples/qgis.core/QgsVectorLayer/addExpressionField/python-qgsvectorlayer-addexpressionfield-method-examples.html)