# Adding field to PostgreSQL vector layer without committing it to data source using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I'm loading in a few PostgreSQL tables in my QGIS plugin, I want to keep track of some extra information in the layer by using fields but I don't want to save these fields as columns in PostgreSQL.

Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating Virtual Field in QGIS Python Console](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144241/creating-virtual-field-in-qgis-python-console). A virtual field acts like an attribute field but it does not persist in the data source, it is saved in the QGIS project, see [the documentation here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?#creating-a-virtual-field)

Comment: @Matt That is exactly what I need, thank you.